# How can I check the 21 characters starting from 1de2458 in windbg?

Tags: windbg

After reading the docs,I'm doing it this way:

```
ds /c 21 1de2458
```

But only get a screen of `??`,how to do it the right way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely the address doesn't point to a [STRING](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646987%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), ANSI_STRING or UNICODE_STRING structure (these are C style structs for representing strings and they hold more that just the characters).

If you want to dump memory as characters use the `da` command for Ascii or `du` for Unicode characters. This works for e.g. strings in .NET.